# Using query to match object and then get all objects associated via foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to create a job board where a user can search for jobs by zip code. I separated information about the `Business` into one model and the `Job` into another. The `Business` has the address, state, phone number fields etc, while `Job` has information about the job itself. I designed it this way so the user would not have to reenter information about the physical business every time a job is posted. However now when I try and query the `Job`s matching the zip code entered, I really have to grab the `Business` objects matching that zip code and then grab the `Job` objects associated with them?  Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)


class Job(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

views.py:

```
def search_results(request):
    query =request.GET.get('query') 
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(zipcode = query) # tried this before realizing the `zipcode` field was part of the `Business` model and not the `Job` model.
    return render(request, 'job/search_results.html', { 'jobs': jobs})
```

Thanks for any help. Also, this seems like a question that is probably very common but I was not sure what term to search to find the answer to it, so if this is closed but you can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You want to access the `Business` through the `Job` model like so using `__`:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(business__zip_code=query)
```

> More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can match the related jobs with:

```
def search_results(request):
    query =request.GET.get('query') 
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(business__zipcode=query)
    return render(request, 'job/search_results.html', { 'jobs': jobs})
```

One can look "through" relations by using double underscores (`__`).

If you need to show the related business of the `Job`s as well, then it might be worth to perform a `.select_related(..)` on the `Business` model:

```
def search_results(request):
    query =request.GET.get('query') 
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(business__zipcode=query).select_related('business')
    return render(request, 'job/search_results.html', { 'jobs': jobs})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query through `Business` FK:

```
Job.objects.filter(business__zip_code=your_code)
```

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name).